# ping command always returns zero exit code in cygwin

Tags: shell-script, ping, cygwin

I just noticed the `ping` command always returns zero exit code in cygwin.

I installed it as a package `ping`.

Actual output:

```
$ ping 192.168.0.102 -c 1
PING 192.168.0.102 (192.168.0.102): 0 data bytes
36 bytes from 192.168.0.11: icmp_type=3 (Dest Unreachable) icmp_code=1

----192.168.0.102 PING Statistics----
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss

vlastimil@vb-nb-windows ~
$ echo $?
0
```

Expected output:

```
$ echo $?
1
```

This `ping` package contains non-standard version of `ping` command, which obviously behaves as described in the question.

I tried to uninstall this package and install `inetutils` instead, but there seems to be no `ping` command.

How can I go about solving this issue? (a wrapper, etc.)

**EDIT1:**

**The answer should be written in POSIX for portability. Sorry for forgetting about it.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) approach

---

### Cygwin-specific way (wrapper)

```
# Using ping utility from ping package
# This utility seems to always return 0 exit code
is_host_online_cygwin()
{
    ping_output_raw=$(ping "$1" 64 1)
    ! echo "$ping_output_raw" | grep 'Dest Unreachable' > /dev/null 2>&1
}
```

### Windows-specific way (wrapper) [contest winner]

```
# Using built-in ping utility
# This utility seems to always return 0 exit code
is_host_online_windows()
{
    ping_output_raw=$(ping -n 1 "$1")
    ! echo "$ping_output_raw" | grep 'Destination host unreachable' > /dev/null 2>&1
}
```

### Linux-specific way (direct)

```
# Using ping utility from iputils-ping package
# This utility returns the right exit code, there is no need for a wrapper
is_host_online_linux()
{
    ping -c 1 "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1
}
```

---

## Notes

- I am aware this solution is by far not ideal, but it works
- These functions can be simply executed upon finding out what program as `ping` command we are actually using, and though this is out of the scope of this Q & A, I leave a hint:

  ```
  command -v ping
  ```
- I chose to uninstall the `ping` package from Cygwin and use `is_host_online_windows()` because it is simply faster than the Cygwin program.
- For completeness, I included `is_host_online_linux()`, although unrelated to this question.

Comment: as post info about cygwin ping. The old version was replaced by inetutils version https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2018-07/msg00012.html. The new version now properly report the failure case `$ echo $? 1`

Comment: @matzeri Thanks for the feedback. Seems like I will have to do some changes to the answer. Will do that once I'm home. Thanks.